# How to sort sections of markdown by heading?

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-word, markdown, editor

Given a large markdown file with a structure like:

```
# Main

## Sub main Z
### Title Z
Content Z
### Title B
Content B

## Sub main A
### Title A
Content A
```

How would one sort its sections so that they are in alphabetical order by heading?

```
# Main

## Sub main A
### Title A
Content A

## Sub main Z
### Title B
Content B
### Title Z
Content Z
```

Comment: Literally "any way", or do you mean only a solution that require no programming? Why is your question tagged "python" and "windows"?

Comment: @Inigo code or maybe editor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to use `pandoc`, but in step from AST to markdown was lost many formatting like `new line` and etc.

I found another way to do that. We need only `MS Word`.

1. Open markdown file thought `Word`
2. Create new macro with the next code. We find all headers (`#`) and apply style `Title 1`, `Title 2` and so on. Change the name of style for you.

```vb
Sub insertStyleHeaders()
    Dim hashCount As Integer
    Dim styleStr As String
    
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRng.Find
        .text = "#"
        While .Execute
            oRng.MoveEnd wdParagraph
            If InStr(oRng.text, "# ") Then
                hashCount = Len(oRng.text) - Len(Replace(oRng.text, "#", ""))
                styleStr = "Title " + CStr(hashCount)
                oRng.Select
                oRng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(styleStr)
            End If
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

3. After run macros, right mouse click to: `Expand/Collapse` -> `Collapse All Headings`
4. Now we have next doc. You need to select by mouse group of items and call sort by headings.

[image] [image]

5. After end of sort, select all doc (`Ctrl + A`) and apply `plain text`/`default` style in order to remove header styles.
6. And last, use ruler to shift indents and save file.

[image]

Comment: "in step from AST to markdown was lost many formatting like new line" because you didn't ask Pandoc's Markdown renderer to preserve non-semantic newlines (e.g. `--wrap=preserve` on the command line), or if your intent was that all newlines are to be taken semantically as hardbreaks, you didn't enable the `hard_line_breaks` extension. It's all in the docs.  You should have asked! Your solution apparently worked (good for you) but it made me cringe given that there was a proper way of doing it.

Comment: If everything is so simple, you could give one line of code, and not send to study the documentation for the entire "spaceship".

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant as a way for people to get free labor, which is sadly what a lot of people do. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vampire Who ever said it was easy? Your ask is extremely atypical, and as I pointed out requires code. I hope you're not one of those here who expect someone to your code for your one-off problem. As I said, I was happy to help. You made an inaccurate statement of my solution (my time spent *for you*), so I corrected you. For whatever reason now you deleted your statement. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any solution that does not require you to write some code.

But the programmatic solution is pretty easy if you can code:

1. Parse the Markdown into an AST (abstract syntax tree).
2. Manipulate the AST, reordering nodes as you want.
3. Write the modified AST back to Markdown.

The trick is choosing a Markdown parser that supports the above steps, that lets you do it in the language of your choice, and that lets you do it most easily.

Here are the ones that I personally know that meet these requirements:

### [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org)

Probably the number one Markdown toolkit in the world. Pandoc's native language is Haskell, but it supports many languages. If you're going to do a lot of Markdown stuff down the road, it probably makes sense to become knowledgable in Pandoc anyway.

- It has an option, `--section-divs`, that converts the document into a section hierarchy based on headings, which will make resorting sections at every nesting level almost trivial (if you can code).
- It has (support for filters](https://pandoc.org/filters.html#), which are exactly the solution I am describing.
- It has special support for Lua and [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), which might be the easiest to code.
- You can also [write filters in other languages](https://pandoc.org/filters.html#but-i-dont-want-to-learn-haskell): Python, PHP, Perl, Javascript/Typescript, Groovy, Ruby.
- [A quick web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pandoc+filter+sort+sections&t=osx&ia=web) shows many example filters. With some more searching you might get lucky and find one that does what you want already written, though I doubt it as sorting sections alphabetically seems an uncommon thing to do.

#### [CMark](https://github.com/commonmark/cmark)

The C reference implementation of CommonMark. Languages other than C are supported:

> It provides a shared library (libcmark) with functions for parsing CommonMark documents to an abstract syntax tree (AST), manipulating the AST, and rendering the document to HTML, groff man, LaTeX, CommonMark, or an XML representation of the AST. It also provides a command-line program (cmark) for parsing and rendering CommonMark documents.

> - Flexible. CommonMark input is parsed to an AST which can be manipulated programmatically prior to rendering.
> - Multiple renderers. Output in HTML, groff man, LaTeX, CommonMark, and a custom XML format is supported. And it is easy to write new renderers to support other formats.

> It is easy to use libcmark in python, lua, ruby, and other dynamic languages: see the wrappers/ subdirectory for some simple examples.

#### [remark](https://remark.js.org)

A Javascript-based framework specifically designed around AST manipulation. I've never used it, but it possibly has tools to make AST manipulation easier, though I'm only guessing.

Good luck!